# why cannot I tag one of my answers as answering my own question?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I had the case today where I asked a question and found the answer myself a few hours later.
I then posted the solution by answering my own original question.

Now I'd like to mark my original question as "answered" by clicking my solution as answering my original question. But the system insists that I cannot accept my own answer for my own question.

I am afraid that with time, a lot of questions might be left unanswered and will pile up on the main page of ros answers.

So here is the question: is this behaviour wanted?

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9370/why-cannot-i-tag-one-of-my-answers-as-answering-my-own-question?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-10**:
Ok, good to know that admins clean answered answers. but wouldn't it be more efficient for them to check answers answered by the initial asker? That way they would just need to look for people boosting their karma artificially.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-03-10**:
right now admins have the power to answers their own questions and anyone else's questions.. We periodically go through and see if there are questions that have good answers that have not been accepted

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-10**:
if answering your own question increases karma then we would want this behavior. thats my opinion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a useful (and definitely wanted) feature. I've opened an enhancement ticket for it on the ROS trac: [Ticket #3405](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3405).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-17**:
Just to reinforce the usefulness of it: I just spoted 2 questions like this in the last 10 minutes. It is so typical to have a quick look at the doc, then ask your question here, go back to the doc and find the answer, and post it here. Thanks for making the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the idea is you want one outside source to confirm the answer. I had a similar circumstance a day ago, and someone else came in and checked the "answer" to my own answer to the problem.

Looking at it a little differently from a security perspective. You want to prevent someone from artificially "answering" all his questions and boost his karma. Since this is a self-moderated site, you want to prevent some lone guy from reeking havoc by editing/deleting comments since that's an ability you get once you've earned a high enough karma. Obviously, you don't want just anybody to have this power.

-Shark

---

Originally posted by [Shark](https://answers.ros.org/users/264/shark/) with karma: 241 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I just had the same problem and wanted to add a new thread about this. As it is not olimpic games we're having here, I think the risk of people actually trying to boost their karma by creating artificial questions is really low. I think no one sane would risk his/her reputation to do that. [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) allows accepting your own questions after 24 hours, I think this is good enough.

I've just posted an answer to my own question, and would like to close the case so nobody else wastes her/his time to read my question. I'm not expecting any karma for that. Isn't there an option to not add karma for marking your own question right?

Regards, Tom.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4